# Remove Unicode characters from textfiles - sed , other Bash/shell methods

Tags: bash, unicode, sed, text-files, spaces

How do I remove Unicode characters from a bunch of text files in the terminal?

I've tried this, but it didn't work:

```
sed 'g/\u'U+200E'//' -i *.txt
```

I need to remove these Unicode characters from the text files:

```
U+0091 - sort of weird "control" space
U+0092 - same sort of weird "control" space
A0 - non-space break
U+200E - left to right mark
```

Comment: What encoding is your text files in?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If you want to remove *only* particular characters and you have Python, you can:

```
CHARS=$(python -c 'print u"\u0091\u0092\u00a0\u200E".encode("utf8")')
sed 's/['"$CHARS"']//g' < /tmp/utf8_input.txt > /tmp/ascii_output.txt
```

Comment: Maybe not the prettiest. But it worked very well for me. By constructing the CHARS variable, it made the sed easier to read, and CHARS variable can be easily maintained. Choroba's answer also works, so I guess it's a matter of taste (and if you have Python handy).

Comment: It is an alternative code of python part.`python -c 'print "".join(map(unichr, range(0x80, 0xa0) + range(0x2000, 0x200f))).encode("utf-8")'`

Comment: in recent linux os'es you can write unicode characters by pressing Ctrl+Shift+u followed by the numeric code and <Enter>, e.g.

    `Ctrl+Shift+u 0019 ⏎`

Comment: Is it faster to do an in place edit if all the text is separted by new lines than using `< path > newpath`? Have a massive file, why I ask..

Comment: Comment by kev on Chobra's answer is what I found most useful. You can plug that with this answer to get `CHARS=$(echo -ne '\u200c')` followed by the same `sed` line.

Answer (score 69):

Clear all non-ASCII characters of `file.txt`:

```
$ iconv -c -f utf-8 -t ascii file.txt
$ strings file.txt
```

Options:

```
-c # discard unconvertible characters
-f # from ENCODING
-t # to ENCODING
```

Comment: i want to keep the unicode encoding. sorry, so iconv is not the solution.

Comment: Why can't you just run it in reverse? 
tempf=$(mktemp)
iconv -c -f utf-8 -t ascii file.txt > $tempf
iconv -f ascii -t utf-8 $tempf > file.txt

Comment: UTF-8 is a valid subset of ASCII. The reverse transformation keeps the file unchanged.

Comment: You have just changed my life, kev! You're The Man. Thanks!

Comment: This was it for me. Was breaking my automation with this nonsense. Now it works again!

Comment: @alvas what about

`iconv -c -f utf-8 -t utf-8 file.txt`

Answer (score 35):

For UTF-8 encoding of Unicode, you can use this regular expression for [sed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed):

```
sed 's/\xc2\x91\|\xc2\x92\|\xc2\xa0\|\xe2\x80\x8e//g'
```

Comment: how do i find the mapping from `U+...` to `\xc2\...` ?

Comment: The | doesn't work for me this way in sed, so I had to string a series of sed commands with single replaces together.

Comment: @JonathanW. Wasn't it rather the missing `/g`?

Comment: There are quite a few differences between systems here. MacOS doesn't support the \xNN codes and RHEL requires the use of the -r option for sed to be able to use them. Just something to keep in mind in case you're developing a script on one system and deploying to another (generally not the best idea, but that's never prevented people from doing so) :)

Comment: @JonathanW. maybe you want to add `-e` to the sed command in order to use pipes as within regex

Comment: @OldFart, I believe `-r` would have worked, as @JoeDyndale mentioned.

Answer (score 17):

Use [iconv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv):

```
iconv -f utf8 -t ascii//TRANSLIT < /tmp/utf8_input.txt > /tmp/ascii_output.txt
```

This will translate characters like "Š" into "S" (most similar looking ones).

Comment: they are not ascii, i want to keep them in utf8 but i want to replace these weird spaces into normal null string `""`

Comment: Not what the OP wanted, but I had a need to convert a unicode line-seperator (u2028) into a newline.  I would have preferred to use iconv, but I couldn't figure out how to do it.  Is there a way?

Comment: the -c flag is useful to discard characters that cannot be transliterated, avoiding a fatal error.

Comment: As an alternative to -c, --unicode-subst allows to specify a pattern for the substitution of the character, instead of removing it completely. For example, --unicode-subst='?' allows to replace non-identifiable characters with a question mark.

Comment: @ChrisQuenelle - its years later but did you ever solve your problem? I have the same issue.

Comment: It's been so long, I don't recall how I solved my problem.  I think I got iconv to do what I wanted.

Comment: scrolling down, this was the first answer that worked.

Answer (score 2):

Convert Swift files from UTF-8 to ASCII:

```
for file in *.swift; do
    iconv -f utf-8 -t ascii "$file" > "$file".tmp
    mv -f "$file".tmp "$file"
done
```

*[Swift auto completion not working in Xcode 6 Beta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24103833/swift-auto-completion-not-working-in-xcode-6-beta)*