# sed command with -i option (in-place editing) works fine on Ubuntu but not Mac

Tags: linux, macos, sed, bsd, inplace-editing

I know nothing about Sed but need this command (which works fine on Ubuntu) to work on a Mac OSX:

```
sed -i "/ $domain .*#drupalpro/d" /etc/hosts
```

I'm getting:

```
sed: 1: "/etc/hosts": extra characters at the end of h command
```

Comment: @AnthonySottile: The suggested duplicate is definitely closely related, except that - unlike this question - it specifically asks for a solution that works with _both_ the BSD/macOS and GNU implementations of `sed`.
Thus, people interested in a BSD/macOS-_only_ solution may find more focused answers here.

Comment: @mklement0 yeah the question is *slightly* different, but the answers on both are nearly identical -- imo not worth having two questions _shrugs_

Comment: @AnthonySottile: It was just a suggestion - either way is probably fine - let's let future close-voters decide.

Comment: May be, [BashX](https://github.com/reduardo7/bashx) project can help to you with this kind of problems.

Answer (score 244):

Ubuntu ships with GNU `sed`, where the suffix for the `-i` option is optional. OS X ships with BSD `sed`, where the suffix is mandatory. Try `sed -i ''`

Comment: So just follow the sed -i with single quotes, sed -i '1i export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"' $HOME/.bashrc Still does not work for me

Comment: @pal4life the point is that you need a *separate* set of quotes *before* you start the command, so something like `sed -i '' '1i export PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"' $HOME/.bashrc`

Comment: If you need the same script to work on both macOS (OS X, BSD) and Linux et al, then you must use a backup suffix (e.g. `.bak`) and you must attach it to the `-i` option — `sed -i.bak …`.  If you don't do this, the script will not operate correctly on one of the two platforms.  GNU `sed` does not like the empty argument that the BSD `sed` requires to edit in place; you can't attach the empty argument to `-i` because it is empty and indistinguishable from `-i`.  Also, thanks to contradictory designs, the `-i` option won't be standardized as `-i` by POSIX; it can't reconcile the irreconcileable.

Comment: Oh, and if you don't want the backup, run `rm -f /etc/hosts.bak` after running the `sed`.  That's simpler than trying to work out which variant of `sed` you have installed or other gizmos I've seen suggested.  I hope you keep the file under version control (or otherwise backed up) so that you can recover if there's a bug in your `sed` script.  Of course, the `.bak` file gives you that protection.

Comment: May be, [BashX](https://github.com/reduardo7/bashx) project can help to you with this kind of problems.

Answer (score 199):

To complement [microtherion's helpful, to-the-point answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16746032/45375):

- with a portable solution
- with background information

**tl;dr**:

The equivalent of this ***GNU* `sed`** (standard on most **Linux** distros) command:

```sh
sed -i    's/foo/bar/' file
```

is this ***BSD/macOS* `sed`** command:

```sh
sed -i '' 's/foo/bar/' file  # Note the '' as a *separate argument*
```

With ***BSD/macOS* `sed`**, the following commands **do *not* work** at all or not as intended:

```sh
sed -i    's/foo/bar/' file  # Breaks; script is misinterpreted as backup-file suffix
sed -i''  's/foo/bar/' file  # Ditto
sed -i -e 's/foo/bar/' file  # -e is misinterpreted as backup-file suffix
```

For a discussion of *all* the differences between GNU `sed` and BSD/macOS `sed`, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24276470/45375) of mine.

**Portable approach**:

<sup>Note: *Portable* here means that the command works with both implementations discussed. It is not portable in a *POSIX* sense, because [the `-i` option is not POSIX-compliant](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html).</sup>

```sh
# Works with both GNU and BSD/macOS Sed, due to a *non-empty* option-argument:
# Create a backup file *temporarily* and remove it on success.
sed -i.bak 's/foo/bar/' file && rm file.bak
```

For an explanation, see below; for alternative solutions, including a POSIX-compliant one, see [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44877280/45375) of mine.

---

#### Background information

In *GNU* `sed` (standard on most Linux distros) and *BSD/macOS* `sed`, **the `-i` option, which performs *in-place updating*<sup>[1]</sup>
 of its input files, accepts an *option-argument* that specifies what *suffix* (filename extension) to use for the *backup file* of the file being updated**.

E.g., in *both* implementations, the following keeps the original file, `file`, as backup file `file.bak`:

```sh
sed -i.bak 's/foo/bar/' file  # Keep original as 'file.bak'; NO SPACE between -i and .bak
```

Even though [with *GNU* `sed` the suffix argument is *optional*](https://man.cx/sed), whereas with [*BSD/macOS* `sed` it is *mandatory*](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sed.1.html), the above syntax works with *both* implementations, because **directly adjoining the option-argument (`.bak`) to the option (`-i`) - `-i.bak`, as opposed to `-i .bak` - works both as an *optional* and a *mandatory* option-argument**:

- Syntax `-i.bak` is the *only* form that works for an *optional* option-argument.
- Syntax `-i.bak` *also* works as a *mandatory* option-argument, as an *alternative* to `-i .bak`, i.e., specifying the option and its argument *separately*.

**Not specifying a suffix** - which is often the case - means that **no backup file** should be kept, and that is where **the incompatibility arises**:

- With *GNU* `sed`, not specifying a suffix means simply using `-i` *by itself*.
- With *BSD/macOS* `sed`, not specifying a suffix means specifying *the empty string* as the - mandatory - suffix, and **for *technical* reasons, the empty string can only be passed as a *separate* argument**: that is, `-i ''` *not* `-i''`.

**`-i''` doesn't work, because to `sed` it is indistinguishable from just `-i`**, because the *shell* effectively *removes* the empty quotes (it concatenates `-i` and `''` and removes quotes with syntactical function), and passes just `-i` in *both* cases.

With (effectively) just `-i` specified, it is the *next* argument that is interpreted as the option-argument:

```sh
sed -i 's/foo/bar/' file # BREAKS with BSD/macOS Sed
```

`'s/foo/bar/'` - intended to the the Sed *script* (command) - is now interpreted as the *suffix*, and the word `file` is interpreted as the script.
Interpreting such a word as script then leads to obscure error message such as
`sed: 1: "file": invalid command code f`,
because the `f` is interpreted as a Sed command (function).

Similarly, with:

```sh
sed -i -e 's/foo/bar/' file # CREATES BACKUP FILE 'file-e'
```

**`-e` is interpreted as the *suffix* argument, and NOT as Sed's `-e` option** (which can be used to specify *multiple* commands, if needed).
As as result, **instead of keeping NO backup, you get a backup file with suffix `-e`.**

That this command doesn't work as intended is less obvious, because the in-place updating does succeed, given that the syntax requirement of the suffix argument is satisfied by the `-e` argument.

That the accidental creation of these backup files easily goes unnoticed is the likeliest explanation for [Crt's incorrect answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37818583/45375) and [this incorrect answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2321958/45375) having received so many up-votes (as of this writing).

---

<sup>[1] Strictly speaking, a temporary file is created behind the scenes that then *replaces* the original file; this approach can be problematic: see the bottom half of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30066428/45375) of mine.</sup>

Comment: This is the correct and most informative answer to the question. Not sure who downvoted it but no reasons have been expressed for the downvote while I have many reasons to accept this over the other answers.

Comment: I'm not an expert here, but, to keep POSIX compliance, would `mv file file.bak && sed 's/foo/bar/' file.bak > file && rm file.bak` work?

Comment: @CássioRenan: In principle, yes, but `sed 's/foo/bar' file > file.bak && mv file.bak file` (as shown in [one linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44877280/45375)) is simpler. If `-i` is available and portability is not a concern, its use is preferable, because it makes some effort to preserve the original file's attributes, though it notably still destroys a symlink - see the 2nd half of [another linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30066428/45375). The POSIX-compliant approach not only also has the symlink problem, but simply creates a new file with the default permissions, ...

Answer (score 23):

man is your friend.

### OS X

```
 -i extension
         Edit files in-place, saving backups with the specified extension.
         If a zero-length extension is given, no backup will be saved.  It
         is not recommended to give a zero-length extension when in-place
         editing files, as you risk corruption or partial content in situ-
         ations where disk space is exhausted, etc.
```

Answer (score 13):

In OS X, you can use the GNU version of sed: `gsed`.

```
# if using brew
brew install gnu-sed

#if using ports
sudo port install gsed
```

Then, if your script should be portable, depending on your OS you can define which command to use.

```
SED=sed
unamestr=`uname`
if [[ "$unamestr" == "Darwin" ]] ; then
    SED=gsed
    type $SED >/dev/null 2>&1 || {
        echo >&2 "$SED it's not installed. Try: brew install gnu-sed" ;
        exit 1;
    }
fi
# here your sed command, e.g.:
$SED -i "/ $domain .*#drupalpro/d" /etc/hosts
```

Comment: This is the one that saved me. I upgraded my install and added /usr/local/opt/gnu-sed/libexec/gnubin to my path. I'm on OSX 10.12.6.

Comment: this should be accepted solution

Comment: Nice handling of dependency on gnu SED, very helpful!