# Problem with sed command in Jenkinsfile in Groovy

Tags: groovy, sed, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to use `sed` in a Groovy file that is being executed by a Jenkinsfile.

My code is:

```
sh script: """
sed -i '' "s/search/substitute/g" "path/to/file"
"""
```

The intention is to change the `search` elements within a file `path/to/file`
to `substitute`.

I can confirm the `sed` code, if executed manually in a terminal, works correctly.

But I'm getting the following error:
`sed: can't read s/search/substitute/g: No such file or directory`

I've tried to invert the order of the search and path arguments without success.

When I get that error the quotes around `s/search/substitute/g` don't appear but

I've tried `'s/search/substitute/g'`, `"s/search/substitute/g"`, `\"s/search/substitute/g\"` and  `\'s/search/substitute/g\'` getting the same error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps tangentially, understand that quoting affects how the _shell_ parses something, and has no effect on `sed` itself. (The backslashed quotes are obviously doubly wrong; they mean nothing to either the shell or to `sed`.)

Comment: For background information on the cross-platform / cross-`sed`-implementation differences of `sed`'s `-i ` option, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44864004/45375).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently your `sed` version does not require an argument for the `-i` option. Thus `''` is interpreted as your script, and `s/search/substitute/g` as the name of a file to process.

Generally, BSD (and thus Mac) `sed` requires an argument to `-i`, whereas Linux doesn't.

Assuming your Jenkins can reliably be expected to run Linux, the simplest solution is to just drop the `''`.

If you want to create a script which works regardless of platform, maybe pass a non-empty argument directly after `-i`, like `-i~`. (Probably take care to remove the file it creates afterwards. In case it's not obvious, this tells `sed` to save the original input file with a tilde after its name.)

Another solution is to switch to Perl, which supports the same option and *roughly* similar syntax for substitutions; though note that Perl's regex dialect has many features which are absent from traditional `sed` (but basically backwards-compatible with the ERE dialect available in some `sed` implementations with `-E` or `-r`). Perhaps most notably if you are coming from `sed`, don't backslash grouping parentheses, the `+` and `?` quantifers, etc.

```
perl -pi -e "s/search/substitute/g" "path/to/file"
```

Using double quotes around the `sed` or Perl script is pesky; probably prefer single quotes unless you specifically require the shell to perform variable expansion and command substitution when parsing the command line. (Even then, it's often convenient to use single quotes around the parts which don't require the shell to meddle.)

```
sed -i 's/static text/'"$variable and $(command output)"'/g' path/to/file
```