# How to substitute the characters à, è, ì, ò, ù in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed

I've got to rename a file such that: IndennitàMalattia.doc 
by replacing the character à with `a'`.

The following sed command works in the command line, but not inside a .sh file.

```
echo $FILE | sed -e s/à/a\'/g
```

Can someone please help me? 
Thanks!

Comment: You might have an encoding problem.  Make sure that the file and your terminal environment are both using UTF-8.  (e.g. `export LC_ALL=it_IT.UTF-8` for the shell, and `:set filenecoding=utf8` in vim).

Comment: Related and useful: [How to remove all of the diacritics from a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10207354/how-to-remove-all-of-the-diacritics-from-a-file)

Answer (score 2):

Change your sed like below,

```
echo $FILE | sed "s/à/a'/g"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mv "${File}" "$( echo "${File}" | sed "s/à/a'/g;s/è/e'/g;s/ì/i'/g;s/ò/o'/g;s/ù/u'/g" )"
```

and any other accent char equivalent

Answer (score 0):

You may find this Perl script useful.  It will rename specified files by turning all grave accents into apostrophes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use v5.14;
use autodie;
use warnings;
use warnings qw( FATAL utf8 );
use utf8;
use open qw ( :encoding(UTF-8) :std );
use charnames qw( :full :short );

use Unicode::Normalize;

# if no args specified, use example from question
@ARGV = qw(IndennitàMalattia.doc) unless @ARGV;  

foreach my $old_name (@ARGV) {
  (my $new_name = NFD($old_name)) =~ s/\N{COMBINING GRAVE ACCENT}/'/g;
  say qq{Renaming "$old_name" to "$new_name"};
  rename $old_name, NFC($new_name);
}
```