# How to create username from full name without diacritic in linux

Tags: linux

which command in linux can convert my name into username like:
name :Lê Thành Việt 
--> convert to: le.thanh.viet ( not lê.thành.việt )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10207623/4311135) and [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-shell-programming-converting-lowercase-uppercase/)

```
echo "Lê Thành Việt" | iconv -f UTF-8 -t ascii//TRANSLIT  | tr ' ' '.' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'
```

Comment: I tested this on Darwin and on OpenBSD (because I've thought about _similar_ problems). On OpenBSD it works, but on Darwin I get `iconv: (stdin):1:11: cannot convert` followed by the result `l^e.th``anh.vit`...

Comment: @Kusalananda probably you need to read the manuals for the iconv utility for Darwin.

Comment: I was actually on a Linux system when it worked, on OpenBSD it doesn't. I need to remember where I'm logged in! (note to self: put host name in `$PS1`). The manuals are identical on all three systems.

Comment: @Kusalananda I have no clue why it doesn't work on OpenBSD and Darwin, may be there is some difference in utf8 decoding. I think you can open another question and tag it with OpenBSD and Darwin tags