# Replace Â with space in a file

Tags: unix, sed, character-encoding

In my file somehow Â is getting added. I am not sure what it is and how it is getting added.

```
12345AÂ 210Â CBCDEM
```

I want to remove this character from the file . I tried basic sed command to get it remove but unsuccessful.

```
  sed -i -e 's/\Â//g'
```

I also read that  `dos2unix`  will do the job but unfortunately that also didn't work .Assuming it was hex character I also tried to remove it using hex value  `sed -i 's/\xc2//g'`  but that also didnt work

I really want to understand what this character is and how it is getting added. Moreover , is there possible way to delete all such characters in a file .

Adding encoding details  :--

```
file test.txt 
test.txt: ISO-8859 text
echo $LANG
en_US.UTF-8
```

OS Details :--

```
uname -a
Linux vm-testmachine-001 3.10.0-693.11.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Oct 27 05:39:05 EDT 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Regards.

Comment: How is the file created?

Comment: The file is getting created as export from Mongo . Mongo doesnt have such characters.

Comment: Sure. Can you check the encoding your system uses vs the encoding your database uses?

Comment: This should be useful I guess [How to remove all of the diacritics from a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10207354/how-to-remove-all-of-the-diacritics-from-a-file)

Comment: Try running `file <filename>` and include the result in your question. Something like `od -c <filename> | head` might also be useful. We need more information.

Comment: @Mad Physicist My unix machine encoding is en_US.UTF-8 . Mongo also I assume by default should be utf 8 .

Comment: How do you see the Â characters? A graphical text editor? `cat`?

Comment: Oh wait, the encoding of the file is very much not UTF-8. There's your problem.

Comment: iconv options -f ISO-8859 -t en_US.UTF-8 test.txt -o test.txt
iconv: conversions from `ISO-8859' and to `en_US.UTF-8' are not supported
This also fails.

Comment: just plain `utf8` or `utf-8`. `en_US` is a locale. It specifies the digit separators, currency symbol, date format, etc that you use. The character encoding is UTF-8. The two things are completely independent of each other in most cases.

Comment: Also, be careful about setting the output file to the input file. You may end up truncating the input before you have a chance to read it. I would try it on a throwaway file first.

Comment: Look up the actual encoding used by your DB. Remember that the `file` program uses a heuristic to determine the encoding of a text file. It looked for non-ascii characters in the file and output the *most likely* encoding given the output found. I suspect that your `Â ` combinations are intended to be some weird tab or newline combinations, but I can't say without knowing the intended encoding for sure.

Comment: Another thing that would really help is if you could do a hex dump of the original snippet you posted. Seeing the binary values might help identify it as well

Comment: Final point, why did you do `sed -i -e 's/\Â//g'`? Does plain old `sed -i -e 's/Â//g'` not work? I would expect that the backslash is the only thing tripping you up there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have an encoding mismatch between the program that writes the file (in some part of [ISO-8859](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859)) and the program reading the file (assuming it to be [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)). This is a textbook use-case for [`iconv`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/iconv). In fact the sample in the man-page is almost exactly applicable to your case:

```
iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8 test.txt
```

`iconv` is a [fairly standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv#History) program on almost every Unix distribution I have seen, so you should not have any issues here.

Based on the fact that you appear to be writing with English as your primary language, you are probably looking for [`iso-8859-1`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), which is quite popular apparently.

If that does not fix your issue, You probably need to find the proper encoding for the output of your database. You can do

```
iconv -l
```

to get a list of encodings available for `iconv`, and use the one that works for you. Keep in mind that the output of `file` saying `ISO-8859 text` is not absolute. There is no way to distinguish things like pure ASCII and UTF-8 in many cases. If I am not mistaken, `file` uses heuristics based on frequencies of character codes in the file to determine the encoding. It is quite liable to make a mistake if the sample is small and/or ambiguous.

If you want to save the output of `iconv` and your version supports the `-o` flag, you can use it. Otherwise, use redirection, but carefully:

```
TMP=$(mktemp)
iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8 test.txt > "$TMP" && mv "$TMP" test.txt
```

Comment: It keeps giving error  iconv: conversion from `ISO-8859' is not supported

Comment: @user2854333. Try `iso8859`. What OS are you actually on? Please edit that into the question.

Comment: iso8859 also doesnt work . I did iconv -l to get the supported conversion format and it seems  iso-8859 is not there we need to have iso-8859-1 or something like that .

Comment: I tried it  but the characters still exists although encoding has changed.

Comment: @user2854333. I added an update that may help with that. My version of `iconv` does not allow for output files. Also, could you show the actual command that you use to output your text file?

Comment: Iso-8859 is not a valid encoding name. I assume the comments above were trying to say `iso-8859-1`

Comment: @tripleee. Fixed, removed all mentions of iso-8859.

Comment: I'd still like to emphasize that the OP's question is almost certainly asking the wrong thing. You *don't* want to "replace Â"; this common symptom of an encoding problem should be fixed by correcting the encoding. Indeed, I already upvoted this answer yesterday, while it still had some minor technical issues.

Comment: It didnt help unfortunately . I still the characters in file.

Comment: @user2854333. "It didnt help unfortunately" is not a very helpful comment. I've made numerous requests for additional information in the comments on the question itself which you've completely ignored. I can't really help you without that information, so I've added my close vote until you provide it.