# How to replace Unicode characters with ASCII

Tags: bash, shell, unix, unicode, sed

I have the following command to replace Unicode characters with ASCII ones.

```
sed -i 's/Ã/A/g'
```

The problem is `Ã` isn't recognized by the sed command in my Unix environment so I'd assume you replace it with its hexadecimal value. What would the syntax look like if I were to use `C3` instead?

I'm using this command as a template for other characters i'd like to replace with blank spaces such as:

sed -i 's/©/ /g'

Comment: you mean like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22450563/sed-matching-unicode-blocks-with

Comment: What character set does your terminal use? And what encoding does the input text use? Ã in UTF-8 is 0xC3 0x83, and character 0x83 is a control code in ISO 8859-1, so that might be a problem. I suppose you can’t just set `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` on your system.

Comment: "sed" will do the job. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 20):

It is possible to use hex values in "sed".

```
echo "Ã" | hexdump -C
00000000  c3 83 0a                                          |...|
00000003
```

Ok, that character is two byte combination "c3 83". Let's replace it with single byte "A":

```
echo "Ã" |sed 's/\xc3\x83/A/g'
A
```

Explanation: \x indicates for "sed" that a hex code follows.

Comment: Usually I would write those with <<< but piping gives better idea for an average reader what's going on.

Comment: What do you mean "write them with <<<"?

Comment: In case you were wondering what the `0a` in the hexdump was, it is the `LF` character from the `echo`. That's why it's ignored. Or you could use `echo -n` to not print the `LF`.

Comment: I had to pass all the three parts (not two) to sed to successfully replace 'e2 80 af' character. Can this be a general rule?

Answer (score 9):

You can use iconv:

```
iconv -f utf-8 -t ascii//translit -o output.txt input.txt
```

Comment: You mean GNU iconv. Not all versions of iconv support transliteration.

Comment: Yes, but he can give it a try

Comment: Thanks but i'm using this as a template to create other sed commands that will replace certain characters with blank spaces for example:
sed -i 's/©/ /g'

Answer (score 8):

Try setting `LANG=C` and then run it over the Unicode range:
 
`echo "hi ☠ there ☠" | LANG=C sed "s/[\x80-\xFF]//g"`

Answer (score 4):

There is also `uconv`, from [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/).

Examples:

- `uconv -x "::NFD; [:Nonspacing Mark:] > ; ::NFC;"`: to remove accents
- `uconv -x "::Latin; ::Latin-ASCII;"`: for a transliteration latin/ascii
- `uconv -x "::Latin; ::Latin-ASCII; ([^\x00-\x7F]) > ;"`: for a transliteration latin/ascii and removal of remaining code points > 0x7F
- ...

`echo "À l'école ☠" | uconv -x "::Latin; ::Latin-ASCII; ([^\x00-\x7F]) > ;"`

gives: `A l'ecole`