# How to get uniq strings with different charset

Tags: linux, bash, awk, character-encoding

I have a file 1.txt

```
$ cat 1.txt 
page1
рage1
```

But:

```
$ head -n1 1.txt | file -i -
/dev/stdin: text/plain; charset=us-ascii

$ head -n2 1.txt | tail -n1 | file -i -
/dev/stdin: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

Strings have different charset. Because of it I can't get unique string with the method i know:

```
$ cat 1.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
      1 рage1
      1 page1
```

So, can you help me to find the way how to get only unique string in my situation?
P.S. Prefer solutions only with linux command line/bash/awk. 
But if you have the solution in another programming language, I'd like it too.

Upd. `awk '!a[$0]++' Input_file` don't work, pic:

[image]

Comment: Could you `head -2 1.txt | hexdump -C`

Comment: @anubhava output is ```M-QM-^@age1$
page1$
```

Comment: @JamesBrown ```00000000  d1 80 61 67 65 31 0a 70  61 67 65 31 0a           |..age1.page1.|
0000000d
```

Comment: First one is not a p: "U+0440 р d1 80 CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER ER". No easy fix, replace replace replace.

Comment: Oh, jesus. @JamesBrown you are right, it's really cyrillic `р`, not english `p`. So dumb question, Thanks! P.S. Can you tell me, who you get this info? ```"U+0440 р d1 80 CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER ER"```

Comment: I googled: utf8 "d1 80". :D

Comment: did you try [iconv](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/iconv.1.html)?

Comment: @mvrma yea, but it's too bad: ```$ iconv -f utf8 -t us-ascii//TRANSLIT 1.txt 
page1
?age1```

Comment: @ViktorKhilin converting the whole file doesn't work?

Comment: Maybe you could give `konwert`a try ? apparently it is more sturdy than iconv. There is a debian package available [here](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/text/konwert), I couldn't test it myself as I am currently on a mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cursory examination of what we have here:

```
$ cat 1.txt
page1
рage1
$ hd 1.txt
00000000  70 61 67 65 31 0a d1 80  61 67 65 31 0a           |page1...age1.|
0000000d
```

As noted in the comments to the question, that second "рage1" is indeed distinct from the previous "page1" for a reason:  that's not a Latin `p`, it's a Cyrillic `р`, so a uniqueness filter should call them out as separate unless you normalize the text beforehand.

iconv won't do the trick here.  [uconv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uconv) (e.g. `apt install icu-devtools` on Debian/Ubuntu) will get you close, but its [transliteration mappings](http://uconv.com/translit.htm) are based on phonetics rather than lookalike characters, so when we transliterate this example, the Cyrillic `р` becomes a Latin `r`:

```
$ uconv -x Cyrillic-Latin 1.txt
page1
rage1
```

See also [these more complex `uconv` commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33678333/519360), which have similar results.

The [ICU uconv man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/uconv) states

> **uconv** can also run the specified *transliteration* on the transcoded data, in which case transliteration will happen as an intermediate step, after the data have been transcoded to Unicode. The *transliteration* can be either a list of semicolon-separated transliterator names, or an arbitrarily complex set of rules in the ICU transliteration rules format.

This implies that somebody could use the "ICU transliteration rules format" to specify a lookalike character mapping.  Of course, at that rate, you could use whatever language you want.

I also tried perl's [Text::Unidecode](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Text-Unidecode/), but that has its own (similar) issues:

```
$ perl -Mutf8 -MText::Unidecode -pe '$_ = unidecode($_)' 1.txt
page1
NEURage1
```

That might work better in some cases, but obviously this isn't one of them.