# Using sed, how can a regular expression match Chinese characters?

Tags: regex, bash, utf-8, sed, chinese-locale

I decided to post a question, after spending quite some time and still not figuring out the problem. Also read a bunch of seemingly related posts, none really fit my simple (?) problem.

So I have a possibly large text file (>1000 lines) that contains Mandarin Chinese chars, with a sample line like:

```
"ref#2-5-1.jpg#2#一些 <variable> 内容#pic##" (the Chinese just means "some content").
```

All that needs to be modified is that a space should be inserted between each character, if there is not one already:

```
"ref#2-5-1.jpg#2#一 些 <variable> 内 容#pic##".
```

I started naively with straightforward stuff like the following, but there is no match at all:

```
sed -e 's/\([\u4E00-\u9fff]\)/\1 /g' <test_utf_sed.txt > test_out.txt
```

where 4E00-9fff are supposed to be the code range for Mandarin Chinese. 
Unamazingly, this has not worked, so I also had wanted to try

```
sed -e 's/\([一-龻]\)/hello/g' <test_utf_sed.txt > test_out.txt
```

This failed because my bash cannot display (?) the "一" character.

Then I did some basic test, which failed as well:

```
sed -e 's/\(\u4E00\)/hello/g' <test_utf_sed.txt > test_out.txt //一
sed -e 's/\(\u4E9B\)/hello/g' <test_utf_sed.txt > test_out.txt //些
```

Same with another notation for utf encoding (found here on stackoverflow):

```
sed -e 's/\(\u'U+4E00\)/hello/g' <test_utf_sed.txt > test_out.txt
```

1) As tool for dealing with double byte chars, is sed the right choice at all?

2) Is sed able to handle unicode at all, or do I need a special switch?

3) I am *not* looking for a workaround solution like this:

```
step1: insert space after each character 
  //like 's/\(.\)/\1 /g')
step2: remove space after each chacter which is not a Chinese character 
  //like 's/\([a-zA-Z0-9]\) /\1/g')
```

I know how to do this but it is unelegant and error-prone. This must be possible using utf-8 in regex in sed.

4) My environment is **bash-3.2** on a **MacOS 10.6.8** (oldish OS).

5) If you know of any pointers to some open regEx-onliners as library dealing with Chinese text or language processing, it would be great to share.

Thanks a lot in advance, your help is much appreciated!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8562354/remove-unicode-characters-from-textfiles-sed-other-bash-shell-methods

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perl has pretty good support for dealing with Unicode. That might be a better bet for your task than sed. This one-liner works like your first sed example:

```
perl -CIOED -p -e 's/\p{Script_Extensions=Han}/$& /g' filename
```

The `-CIOED` tells perl to do its I/O in utf8. `-p` runs the given code once for each line of the input file, then prints the result. `-e` specifies a line of Perl code to run. See [the documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) on command-line arguments for more.

The regular expression uses [named ranges](http://perldoc.perl.org/perluniprops.html) to identify the characters to match.

You might also want to read the [Perl Unicode](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html) documentation.

Comment: Hi Evan, thanks so much, that worked :) I finally added a "look-around condition" to make sure the space is only added if there is none yet:                           'perl -CIOED -p -e 's/\p{Block=CJK_Unified_Ideographs}**(?! )**/$& /g' filename'

Comment: Thanks for such a neat answer, terrific!!

Answer (score 2):

`sed` doesn't understand `\u` escape sequences (apparently). I don't know if bash-3.2 does either, but I think it does; if so, you could write

```
sed $'s/\u4E9B/hello/g'
```

but you still wouldn't be able to do the range specification.

However, by translating to UTF-8 by hand, you could arrive at the following *extended regular expression* which will, I believe, match any UTF-8 sequence for a character in the range U+4E00...U+9FFF:

```
(\xe4[\xb8-\xbf][\x80-\xbf]|[\xe5-\xe9][\x80-\xbf][\x80-\xbf])
```

(But the character ranges will only work if you invoke `sed` in a single-byte locale, preferably the `C` locale.)

With GNU `sed`, you get extended regular expressions if you provide the `-r` flag. With MacOSX I believe you need the `-E` flag. So you could try:

```
LANG=C sed -E \
       $'s/(\xe4[\xb8-\xbf][\x80-\xbf]|[\xe5-\xe9][\x80-\xbf][\x80-\xbf])/\\1 /g' \
       <test_utf_sed.txt >test_out.txt
```

(The above lets bash handle the `\x` escapes. If you leave out the `$`, then `sed` will handle the `\x` escapes, but you'll have to change the substitution from `\\1` to `\1`. I don't have a Mac, nor do have the old version of bash, so I really don't know whether your `sed` does hex escapes or not; I'm pretty sure that your bash will, but I can't guarantee it.)

---

By the way, it's not that difficult to get the utf-8 encodings for those characters; I did it with a little copy-and-paste from the original post. Eg.:

```
$ hd <<<"一些"
00000000  e4 b8 80 e4 ba 9b 0a                              |.......|
```

It helps to know that the entire range of plane 0 ideographs (U+4E00...U+9FFF) have three-byte codes, so that 一 is `E4 B8 80` and 些 is `E4 BA 9B`. (The `0A` is, of course, a line-end.)

Comment: Hi rici, thanks so much for looking into this and translating utf-8 to unicode! Unfort., i get an error (illegal byte sequence), although i tried this very simple string: 'sed -E $'s/\(\xe4\)/\1 /g' > filename'. I would track the idea further otherwise.

Comment: @Lena: The UTF-8 code for a Chinese character is three bytes long; adding a space after the first byte (`\xe4`) will produce an invalid byte sequence. I don't know what generated that error, but it is certainly not wrong. For a simple case, try `\xe4\xba\x9b`, which is the utf-8 code for 些. I forgot a minor detail in the `sed` invocation, though; see edit (if you care).

Comment: low prio comment: thx again! let me look into this in the weekend. i am no professional programmer (any more) so reading takes some time.