# Remove non UTF-8 characters from an XML file, using sed

Tags: regex, xml, utf-8, sed, xmllint

A given XML file with UTF-8 declared as the encoding does not pass `xmllint`. With the assumption that a non UTF-8 character is causing the error, the following `sed` command is being run against the file. `sed 's/[^\x00-\x7F]//g' file.xml`. Either the command is wrong, or non UTF-8 characters are not the problem, as `xmllint` still fails after running the `sed`. The first question is: does the `sed` regex appear correct?

= = = = =

Here is the output of `xmllint`:

`$ xmllint file.xml
file.xml:35533: parser error : CData section not finished
<p class="imgcont"><img alt="Diets of 2013" src="h
<b>What You Eat: </b>Foods low in sugar and carbs and high in fat—80% of cal
                                                                  ^
file.xml:35533: parser error : PCDATA invalid Char value 31
<b>What You Eat: </b>Foods low in sugar and carbs and high in fat—80% of cal
                                                                  ^
file.xml:35588: parser error : Sequence ']]>' not allowed in content
as.people.com/2013/11/07/kerry-washington-pregnant-diet-green-smoothie-recipe/"]
                                                                               ^`

= = = = =

**UPDATE:** In TextMate, on viewing the file, there is a character that is being shown as `<US>`. If that character is manually deleted from the file, the file then passes `xmllint`.

Comment: The character `<US>` is code point `\x1f`. What does xmllint say is the error?

Comment: You want to have a look at [Why are “control” characters illegal in XML 1.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/404107/why-are-control-characters-illegal-in-xml-1-0).

Comment: @Phylogenesis: Updated question with output of `xmllint`.

Comment: @halfbit: Thanks. Does it seem that the `sed` regex would need to be modified, to strip out control characters?

Comment: Yes, according to [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#charsets) the only characters between `\x00` and `\x1f` that are valid are `\x09`, `\x0a` and `\x0d`.

Comment: sed works on characters not on bytes. If the encoding of the file is wrong, you've no idea what sed will see. You need a tool that works at the binary level, not the character level.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using sed, how can a regular expression match Chinese characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23188189/using-sed-how-can-a-regular-expression-match-chinese-characters)

Answer (score 0):

It is somewhat hard to work with `sed` to remove specific code points from Unicode table.

In case you need to target specific Unicode categories of characters it makes more sense to work with Perl.

```
perl -pe -i 's/(?![\t\n\r])\p{Cc}//g' file
```

will remove all control characters but TAB, CR and LF.