# How to match cjk characters with sed?

Tags: regex, sed, unicode, utf-8, cjk

I'd like to match CJK characters. But the following regex `[[:alpha:]]\+` does not work. Does anybody know to match CJK characters?

```
$ echo '程 a b' | sed -e 's/\([[:alpha:]]\+\)/x\1/g'
程 xa xb
```

The desired the output is `x程 a b`.

Comment: use `[[:print:]]`

Comment: I only want to match CJK characters but not other printable characters.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23189067/3776858

Comment: From my own experience, it is much easier with Perl. If there is no rigorous requirement to use sed, do it in Perl, it will be much more comprehensible and concise.

Answer (score 2):

As @WiktorStribiżew suggests, it will be easier to use [perl](/questions/tagged/perl).
If Perl is your option, please try the following:

```
echo "程 a b" | perl -CIO -pe 's/([\p{Script_Extensions=Han}])/x\1/g'
```

Output:

```
x程 a b
```

Answer (score 0):

With Perl, your solution will look like

```
perl -CSD -Mutf8 -pe 's/\p{Han}+/x$&/g' filename
```

Or, with older Perl versions before 5.20, use a capturing group:

```
perl -CSD -Mutf8 -pe 's/(\p{Han}+)/x$1/g' filename
```

To modify file contents inline add `-i` option:

```
perl -i -CSD -Mutf8 -pe 's/(\p{Han}+)/x$1/g' filename
```

**NOTES**

- `\p{Han}` matches a single Chinese character, `\{Han}+` matches chunks of 1 or more Chinese characters
- `$1` is the backreference to the value captured with `(\p{Han}+)`, `$&` replaces with the whole match value
- `-Mutf8` lets Perl recognize the UTF8-encoded characters used directly in your Perl code
- `-CSD` (equivalent to `-CIOED`) allows input decoding and output re-encoding (it will work for UTF8 encoding).