# Swift auto completion not working in Xcode 6 Beta

Tags: swift, xcode6

I made an iOS project with Swift and the Xcode 6 Beta doesn't show any completion for me. But it works with [Playgrounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swift_Playgrounds).

I noticed [some YouTube videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tq0nkr9nhyk) for Swift. The Xcode can show the methods automatically. Should I configure the project or do something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have figured it out. If your Swift files contain Unicode characters, auto completion will fail even if the characters are comments. So just delete all the Unicode characters, and the auto completion feature will work well!

I think this is a Xcode 6 Beta bug!

Answer (score 0):

Not even use as comments, it would lose auto completion if you use Unicode  characters as parameters, such as `sender.setTitle("A♣︎", forState: UIControlState.Normal)`.

You have to delete all Unicode characters. It's really inconvenient. I hope it will be fixed in the next version.