# Encoding: 008D character?

Tags: character-encoding

**Problem:** I have a bunch of txt files written in Portuguese on a Windows machine using NotePad. Some of them seem to have been encoded as ANSI. When I open these files using `gedit` on Ubuntu, some of them contain boxes containing **`008D`** (see screenshot). This is after converting them to UTF-8.

[image: Screenshot gedit]

When I print the file contents to the terminal using `cat`, `head` or `more`, this is the output of the same file. Note that everything from *última vez* up to and including the strange character isn't printed to the terminal.

```
Olá madrinha! Eu gostava de ir contigo passar férias na montanha, porque acho que vai ser divertido e há muito tempo que já não vou a tua casa e na últimaar a ter saudades. Madrinha, não sei porque és tão simpática comigo mas para mim, és a melhor madrinha do mundo inteiro.  Madrinha, ajudas-me sempre que preciso e estás sempre a apoiar-me por isso, quero ir a tua casa para te apoiar a ti.  Obrigada madrinha, por me apoiares.  Muito obrigado madrinha
```

When I open the same file using `atom.io`, everything looks as it should:

[image: Screenshot atom]

**Questions:** Most pressingly: How can I get rid of this character without opening all files and manually deleting them? And secondly, what *is* this, i.e., what should I google to solve similar problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the magical keywords ('remove unicode string using sed'). This does the trick: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8562661/1331521:

```
# Define unicode character you want to remove;
# In this case 008D:
CHARS=$(python -c 'print u"\u008D".encode("utf8")')

# Then run sed on all files in directory
sed -i 's/['"$CHARS"']//g' *
```