# bash - Remove all Unicode Spaces and replace with Normal Space

Tags: bash, unicode, sed, spaces

I have a file with a lot of text, and mixed there are special *space* characters,
those are [Unicode Spaces](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/spaces.html)

I need to replace all of them with the *normal* "space" character.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Easy using perl:

```
perl -CSDA -plE 's/\s/ /g' file
```

but as @mklement0 corectly said in comment, it will match the `\t` (TAB) too. If this is problem, you could use

```
perl -CSDA -plE 's/[^\S\t]/ /g'
```

Demo:

```
X            　X
```

the above containing:

```
U+00058 X LATIN CAPITAL LETTER X
U+01680   OGHAM SPACE MARK
U+02002   EN SPACE
U+02003   EM SPACE
U+02004   THREE-PER-EM SPACE
U+02005   FOUR-PER-EM SPACE
U+02006   SIX-PER-EM SPACE
U+02007   FIGURE SPACE
U+02008   PUNCTUATION SPACE
U+02009   THIN SPACE
U+0200A   HAIR SPACE
U+0202F   NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE
U+0205F   MEDIUM MATHEMATICAL SPACE
U+03000 　 IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE
U+00058 X LATIN CAPITAL LETTER X
```

using:

```
perl -CSDA -plE 's/\s/_/g'  <<<"X            　X"
```

note, for the demo replacing to underscore, prints

```
X_____________X
```

also, doable using pure bash

```
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 spaces=$(printf "%b" "\U00A0\U1680\U180E\U2000\U2001\U2002\U2003\U2004\U2005\U2006\U2007\U2008\U2009\U200A\U200B\U202F\U205F\U3000\UFEFF")

while read -r line; do
    echo "${line//[$spaces]/ }"
done
```

The `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` is necessary only if your default locale isn't `UTF-8`. (which you should have, if do you working with utf8 texts) :)
demo:

```
str="X            　X"
echo "${str//[$spaces]/_}"
```

prints again:

```
X_____________X
```

same using `sed` - prepare the variable `$spaces` as above and use:

```
sed "s/[$spaces]/ /g" file
```

**Edit** - because some strange copy/paste (or Locale) problems:

```
xxd -ps <<<"$spaces"
```

shows

```
c2a0e19a80e1a08ee28080e28081e28082e28083e28084e28085e28086e2
8087e28088e28089e2808ae2808be280afe2819fe38080efbbbf0a
```

the `md5` digest (two different programs)

```
md5sum <<<"$spaces"
LC_ALL=C md5 <<<"$spaces"
```

prints the same `md5`

```
35cf5e1d7a5f512031d18f3d2ec6612f  -
35cf5e1d7a5f512031d18f3d2ec6612f
```

Comment: Something is  wrong with the pure bash version: in my terminal it removes all uppercase 'A's. If I use the python `spaces=$(python -c 'print u"\u0020\u00a0\u1680\u180e\u2000\u2001\u2002\u2003\u2004\u2005\u2006\u2007\u2008\u2009\u200A\u200b\u202f\u205f\u3000\ufeff".encode("utf8")')` it works

Comment: @Kuzeko youre doing something strange. I just added to the test string some `AAA` and nothing got removed. Also your inline python is strange, it contains some non-ascii characters. Do you copied the bash exactly as it is above?

Comment: easy copy&paste check: the result of the `md5sum <<<"$spaces"` should print: `35cf5e1d7a5f512031d18f3d2ec6612f` if not, your copy&paste is wrong.

Comment: yep, md5 doesn't match. What's your  `echo $LC_ALL` ?

Comment: @Kuzeko The `LC_ALL=C mdsum <<<"$spaces"` prints the same `md5`. You clearly doing something strange, because it is only one (full ascii) line for the copy. The locale can't have effect in this case, because the _content_ of the `$spaces`  is piped directly to `md5`. Even the `xxd` or `od` could show exactly the content. Adding it into answer.

Comment: But... you're corect - the locale **affecting** the `printf` itself. You need to have `xx_xx.UTF-8` locale. e.g. `en_US.utf8` Edited the answer.

Comment: Something strange indeed, my `LC_ALL` is set  to `C` for other issues with `sort` and `uniq`

Comment: @Kuzeko You can have `LC_ALL=C` for the whole script. it is enough prepend the `printf` with the `utf8`-based one. See the code above, it wont affects the other parts...

Comment: Nicely done; things worth noting: the use of `\U...` escapes requires Bash 4.x; re `perl` solution: `\s` will also match _tabs_, and replacing them with a single space may  not be desired. A quibble: `printf "%b" '...'` can just be `printf '...'` - no need for the `%b` detour.

Comment: @mklement0 true, i forgot the `\t`. About the `%b` - also true, but me personally like the explicit format. ;) Thanx for the comment. Adding the edit about the `\t`.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to identify the characters by their unicode, the `sed 's/[[:space:]]\+/\ /g'` wont do the trick unfortunately.

By reworking another [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8562661/5973334), we list all the unicodes save them in a variable, then use sed for the replacement (note using `-i.bak` we will also save a copy of the original file)

```
 CHARS=$(printf "%b" "\U00A0\U1680\U180E\U2000\U2001\U2002\U2003\U2004\U2005\U2006\U2007\U2008\U2009\U200A\U200B\U202F\U205F\U3000\UFEFF")

 sed -i.bak 's/['"$CHARS"']/ /g' /tmp/file_to_edit.txt
```

Comment: Nicely done; things worth noting: the use of `\U...` escapes requires Bash 4.x.
`sed 's/[[:space:]]/ /g'` _should_ work, if your `sed` (a) respects the locale's UTF-8 charmap, and (b) that charmap is up-to-date (the latter is not the case on Ubuntu 16.04, for instance) - it would replace _tabs_ too, however.
The `\+` is not necessary and, more importantly, not portable.
Quibbles: `printf "%b" '...'` can just be `printf '...'` - no need for the `%b` detour; better not to use all-uppercase shell variable names.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, feel free to edit the answer adding a code block with your more "stable" solution. I would do so myself but I am not 100% I understand all the suggested edits

Answer (score 1):

**If you're faced with this task repeatedly**, consider installing **[`nws`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nws-cli)** (*n*ormalize *w*hite*s*pace), a utility (of mine) that simplifies the task:

```
nws --ascii file # convert non-ASCII whitespace and punctuation to ASCII

nws --ascii -i file  # update file in place
```

The `--ascii` mode of `nws`:

- transliterates (non-ASCII) Unicode whitespace (such as a no-break space ( )) and punctuation (such as curly quotes (`“”`), en dash (`–`), ... ) to their closest ASCII equivalent
- while leaving any other Unicode characters alone.

This mode is  helpful for source-code samples that have been formatted for display with typographic quotes, em dashes, and the like, which usually makes the code indigestible to compilers/interpreters.

---

#### Installation of `nws` from the [npm registry](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nws-cli) (Linux and macOS)

<sup>Note: Even if you don't use Node.js, `npm`, its package manager, works across platforms and is easy to install; try

[`curl -L https://git.io/n-install | bash`](https://github.com/mklement0/n-install)</sup>

With [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) installed, install as follows:

```
[sudo] npm install nws-cli -g
```

**Note**:

- Whether you need `sudo` depends on how you installed Node.js and whether you've [changed permissions later](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions); if you get an `EACCES` error, try again with `sudo`.
- The `-g` ensures [*global* installation](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-globally) and is needed to put `nws-cli` in your system's `$PATH`.

#### Manual installation (any Unix platform with `bash`)

- Download [this `bash` script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mklement0/nws-cli/stable/bin/nws-cli) as `nws`.
- Make it executable with `chmod +x nws`.
- Move it or symlink it to a folder in your `$PATH`, such as `/usr/local/bin` (macOS) or `/usr/bin` (Linux).

---

#### Optional reading: POSIX character classes `[:space:]` and `[:blank:]` and non-ASCII Unicode whitespace

**In UTF-8-based locales, POSIX-compatible utilities *should* make POSIX character class `[:space:]` and `[:blank:]` match (non-ASCII) Unicode whitespace**.

This relies on the locale charmap's correct classification of Unicode characters based on the [POSIX-mandated character classifications](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap07.html#tag_07_03_01_01), which directly correspond to character classes such as `[:space:]`, available in patterns and regular expressions.

There are two **pitfalls**:

- Unicode is an evolving standard (version 9 as of this writing); **your platform's UTF-8 charmap may not be current**.

  - For instance, on `Ubuntu 16.04` the following characters are not properly classified and therefore not matched by `[:space:]` / `[:blank:]`:
    *no-break space, figure space, narrow no-break space, next line*
- The **utilities *should* use the active locale's charmap** - but there are **regrettable exceptions - the following utilities are NOT Unicode-aware (there may be more)**:

  - Among GNU utilities (as of coreutils v8.27):

    - `cut`, `tr`
  - [Mawk](http://invisible-island.net/mawk/), the `awk` implementation that is the default on Ubuntu, for instance.
  - Among BSD/macOS utilities (as of macOS 10.12):

    - `awk`

Therefore, on a platform that has a current UTF-8 charmap, the following `sed` command should work, but note that `[:space:]` also matches *tab* characters and therefore replaces them with a single space too:

```
sed 's/[[:space:]]/ /g' file
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use python3 this worked for me, its makeshift code but does work.

```
FILENAME = 'File.txt'
OUTPUTNAME = 'Fixed.txt'
f = open(FILENAME, 'r+', encoding='utf8')
o = open(OUTPUTNAME, 'w+', encoding='utf8')
for line in f:
    for ch in line:
        if ch == '\u2003':
            ch = ' '
            o.write(ch)
        else:
            o.write(ch)
o.close()
f.close()
```