# error validating data: [ValidationError(Deployment): unknown field "\u00a0 name" during `kubectl apply -f myfile.yaml`

Tags: validation, kubectl

I was facing the issue during deployment:

```
# kubectl apply -f myfile.yaml
error: error validating "myfile.yaml": error validating data: [ValidationError(Deployment): unknown field "\u00a0 name" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.Deployment, ValidationError(Deployment): unknown field "\u00a0 replicas" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.Deployment, ValidationError(Deployment): unknown field "\u00a0 \u00a0 app" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.Deployment, ValidationError(Deployment): unknown field "\u00a0 \u00a0 \u00a0 - name" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.Deployment, ValidationError(Deployment): unknown field "\u00a0 \u00a0 \u00a0 app" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.Deployment, ValidationError(Deployment): unknown field "
```

Trying to validate it with `yamllint` was no help either:

```
# yamllint myfile.yaml
myfile.yaml
  1:1       warning  missing document start "---"  (document-start)
```

Answer (score 2):

The actual deployment file is irrelevant, as I actually found the solution and pasting here for reference.

Turned out the issue is with unicode spaces, which are impossible to spot when checking the file with `vi` but IMHO should be spotted when checked with `yamllint`. Anyway converting the file as described in [bash - Remove all Unicode Spaces and replace with Normal Space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43638993/bash-remove-all-unicode-spaces-and-replace-with-normal-space) alleviates the issue.

```
# perl -CSDA -plE 's/\s/ /g' myfile.yaml > myfile2.yaml
# kubectl apply -f myfile2.yaml
deployment.apps/xxx created
```

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some invisible special character in your yaml file.
I highly recommend to use :set list command of vi/vim editor.
Its very useful to spot special characters, especially when you working with kubernetes manifests yaml files.

Comment: I tried the `:set list` command in vi to spot the issue, but looks like it does not work in that case. Providing the files for reference: https://github.com/rbogusze/oracleinfrastructure/tree/master/scripto/k3s/bad_yaml where `myfile.yaml` is the one with invisible unicode spaces and `myfile2.yaml` is the cleaned version.

Comment: you have a syntax error on line 26. you are missing extra spaces before configMap

      volumes:
        - name: html-volume
          configMap:
            name: mydog-html