# sed removing the wrong character from string

Tags: sed

I used this command to remove left-to-right mark from a string.

```
# CHARS=$(python -c 'print ("\u200E".encode("utf8"))')

# echo "test be" | sed 's/['"$CHARS"']//g'
test e
```

As seen in the above example sed has removed "b".

why has it removed character "b" and how to remove left-to-right mark?

Comment: Don't run commands as `root`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Python here anyway, why are you not implementing the entire operation in Python?

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input():
     print(line.replace("\u200e", ""), end="")
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/5dV285

If you insist on a one-liner, try with Perl instead of `sed`:

```sh
perl -CSD -pe 's/\x{200e}//g'
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/JAQGu0

If you can get the *proper* UTF-8 encoding of the character into a variable, removing the square brackets should work trivially with most `sed` implementations.

```sh
char=$(python3 -c 'print("\u200e")')
echo "be" | sed "s/$char//g"
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/TrvVJj

Tangentially, [avoid upper case for your private shell variables.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization)

Answer (score 1):

See the output for your `python` snippet to understand why:

```sh
$ python3 -c 'print ("\u200E".encode("utf8"))'
b'\xe2\x80\x8e'
```

You can use [ANSI-C quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html) if your shell supports it:

```sh
$ printf 'a\u200Eb\n' | cat -v
aM-bM-^@M-^Nb

$ printf 'a\u200Eb\n' | sed 's/'$'\u200E''//g' | cat -v
ab
```

Comment: I have not understood the answer. But I guess this is what happens when I blindly copy paste an accepted answer from stack overflow having more than 50 upvotes  :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8562354/remove-unicode-characters-from-textfiles-sed-other-bash-shell-methods/8562661#8562661

Comment: The `python 3` output includes characters like `b` and `'` as well, since it is byte output. I think `python 2` didn't have those characters.

Comment: ok. Got it. But ho do I remove that character from a text file?

Comment: I guess the shell do not support it.

Comment: `$'...'` is a Bash feature; if you are using a different shell, perhaps specify which precise shell you are using.